# Safari omitting elements

Tags: javascript, html, safari, mobile-safari, caspio

I know this is going to be difficult to get help for, but anyway:

**In short:** this page renders OK the **first** time on Safari (both Mac and iPhone/iPad), the second (after refresh) time some things are not shown. Opening the page in Private mode -> works always. Opening it in Chrome -> works always

**In long:** the page is a temporary solution and hacked together... Currently it is driven by Caspio (a no-code rapid development environment). The no-code comes at a price however of a limited possibilities. We are rewriting the system in a proper front-end/back-end environment but for the time-being we should get this page to work.

The page consists of 2 blocks rendered by Caspio. I need to get some elements from block 2 and put them into an element of block 1 (and hide block 2 then) with JS. Again the options on how to get the elements are limited by what Caspio is providing, it's very dirty code which I hope to get rid of asap!

````js
        <script type="text/javascript">
          window.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
            const dataPageId = "46629000bb2da6866c8b4cc09dc1";

            // Default image for the promotion (in case no image uploaded)
            var theImage = document.createElement("img");
            theImage.setAttribute("src", "images/noImageFound.png");
            theImage.setAttribute("alt", "No Image");

            // get the text form the placeholder virtual fields and hide it (not possible in Caspio to hide it)

            // First get the title
            var promoTitleVirtual = document.querySelectorAll("[id*='cbParamVirtual1']");
            
            var promoTitleParagraph = document.createElement("h3");
            var promoTitle = document.createTextNode(promoTitleVirtual[0].value);
            promoTitleParagraph.appendChild(promoTitle);
            promoTitleVirtual[0].style.display = "none";

            // Now the description
            var promoDescriptionVirtual = document.querySelectorAll("[id*='cbParamVirtual2']");
            var promoDescriptionParagraph = document.createElement("span");
            promoDescriptionParagraph.classList.add("w-screen")
            var promoDescription = document.createTextNode(promoDescriptionVirtual[0].value);
            promoDescriptionParagraph.appendChild(promoDescription);
            promoDescriptionVirtual[0].style.display = "none";

            // The Image
            var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

            for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
              if (images[i].src.includes(dataPageId)) {
                theImage = images[i];
              }
            }
            var promotionImage = document.getElementById("promotionImage");

            // reposition the radio so it looks better

            var promoAnswers = document.querySelectorAll(
              "[class*='cbFormBlock24']"
            );

            promotionImage.appendChild(promoTitleParagraph);
            promotionImage.appendChild(theImage);
            promotionImage.appendChild(promoDescriptionParagraph);
            theImage.parentNode.lastChild.style.width = theImage.width + "px";
            promotionImage.appendChild(promoAnswers[0]);
 });```


The image is always shown, the Title and the Description only the first time
````

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem... can be interesting for those using the Caspio environment!
Apparently Caspio doesn't load all the data immediately so even though I wait until everything is loaded :

```
 window.addEventListener("load", function (e)
```

it is not...

Hacky (but this code is it anyway, can't wait until we have this re-written) I added a :

```
 setTimeout(function() {
...
}, 300)
```

to my code so it waits until Caspio is done with its business. (200 was ok, just put 300 to be on the safe side)